# How to total rows in DGV upon load

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, datagridview

Hello I am trying to total the cells of each row in a DGV and add it to a total column upon load.  I have an idea on how to do it but I am not sure where to put the code.  I know I could do something like

```
        int val1 = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value);
        int val2 = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value);
        int val3 = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value);
        int val4 = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].Value);

        int val5 = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[5].Value);
        int val6 = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[6].Value);
        int val7 = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[7].Value);
        int val8 = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[8].Value);

        dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[9].Value = (val1 + val2 + val3 + val4) - (val5 + val6 + val7 + val8);
```

But the issue with that it seems is I have to use an event to trigger the calculation.

Any help on this matter would be appreciated.

Kor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using data binding you can set your row totals in the DataGridView's `DataBindingComplete` event.

The code you provided looks like it will update the totals column but let's refactor it a bit so you can use it in more than one place:

```
private void ComputeAndDisplayRowTotal(int rowIndex) {
    int val1 = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].Value);
    int val2 = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].Value);
    int val3 = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].Value);
    int val4 = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[4].Value);
    int val5 = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[5].Value);
    int val6 = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[6].Value);
    int val7 = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[7].Value);
    int val8 = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[8].Value);

    dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[9].Value = (val1 + val2 + val3 + val4) - (val5 + val6 + val7 + val8);
}
```

Call this method in your `DataBindingComplete` event like this:

```
private void dataGridView1_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e) {
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows) {
        // Don't want to update the total column on the new row at the bottom of the DGV.
        if (!row.IsNewRow) {
            ComputeAndDisplayRowTotal(row.Index);
        }
    }
}
```

Now if you allow the user to edit a cell you can update the row's totals column using the `CellEdnEdit` event, like this:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) {
    ComputeAndDisplayRowTotal(e.RowIndex);
}
```